# Probability of Drawing certain Suits from a Deck of Cards

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, card-games

Let's say I have a standard deck of 52 playing cards, and I need to find a card of a specific suit (lets say spades, for example) and the deck must be sufficiently randomized afterwards. One way to do this of course, is to actually pick up the deck, find a spade, and then shuffle up afterwards. Alternatively, though, what if I were to check the top card of the deck, and if it's a spade then remove it and assume the remainder of the deck is still just as sufficiently shuffled as it was before?

On its face, let's look at the apparent probabilities of drawing cards before and after removing the top card of a full deck this way:
before - each card has a 1/4 chance to be any suit
after - each card in the deck has a 12/51 chance to be a spade, and a 39/51 chance to be any other suit

This seems to me to work out, supposing you knew the probabilities were random upon the initial shuffling of the deck. However, I keep thinking back to the Monty Hall problem. I know it's not exactly applicable here, but I also know that it kind of shows how probabilities can be obscured and changed when you manipulate the objects in question.

What I'm looking for is this: If I find the top card of a shuffled deck to be the suit I'm in search of, do I need to shuffle again afterwards to ensure that my deck is still truly random? Or is the randomness of the remaining 51 cards preserved even after removing the top card?

Comment: Ask yourself this: after removing the first card - because it turned out to be a spade - can you tell anything about any of the remaining cards, apart from the fact that they differ from the card that was removed?

Comment: No, and that's how I would expect it to be randomized after the top card was removed, but this is where the Monty Hall problem pops into my head. In that scenario, you remove one of the objects from the pool of sufficiently randomized possible choices and the probabilities change for some objects but not others.

Comment: Yes, but the Monty Hall problem deals with two indistinguishable objects (i.e., doors without a car), while the cards in your problem are distinguishable.

Comment: So how does this change if we don't care what numbers/faces are on the cards? If, for the purposes of this situation, all spades are treated the same (indistinguishable objects), does the math change?